# Register widget only page is a singular of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, conditional-tags

I've made a custom post type, with a few accompanying widgets, and I was wondering if it is possible to show (some of) these widgets only if you're on a specific page.

Currently I've got

```
function widget($args, $instance)
{
    global $post;
    $links = unserialize(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'links', true ));

    if(!is_singular( 'press_articles' ) || $links == false) {
        unregister_widget( 'Point72_Press_Article_Links_Widget' );
        return false;
    }

    // widget stuff
}
```

But, that doesn't seem to completely remove it, and with that I mean, it removes the widget in the right places, but the positions for the widgets stay even if it's not empty.

So, is there anyway to either remove the empty positions, or not show it at all outside a custom post type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it finally! Wouldn't have been able to without looking at the source of [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/)

This is how it is:
First register a function to filter on `sidebar_widgets`:

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'my_filter_widgets', 10);
```

Then loop through all the widgets, skip over the widgets you don't care about, and if your condition is not met for the widgets you do care about, remove them, like so:

```
function my_filter_widgets($sidebars_widgets)
{
    foreach($sidebars_widgets as $widget_area => $widget_list)
    {
        foreach($widget_list as $pos => $widget_id)
        {
            // We're only after widgets named my_custom_widget, this can vary and you will need to find out, try doing a var_dump() on  $sidebars_widgets
            if(substr($widget_id, 0, 17) != 'my_custom_widget') {
                continue;
            }

            // Those that have not been skipped over, check your condition, and if it doesn't meet the condition, remove it from the $sidebars_widgets array
            if ('press_articles' != get_post_type() || !is_single()) {
                unset($sidebars_widgets[$widget_area][$pos]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nuking the entire widget, you should put your conditional statements within the widget itself:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
     if ( is_singular( array( 'post_type_a', 'post_type_b' ) ) ) {
          // display your widget here
     }
}
```

Since you're not printing `$before_widget` and `$after_widget`, there won't be any output for this widget unless the conditions are met.

Comment: My bad, my current code is already with in the widget function, but I still get an empty position of the widgets area.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. @Hosh Sadiq You've to add the post type names as array.

Comment: @kaiser Not at all. :) Always open for improvement.

Comment: Btw: You should've named yourself _Brain_ Fegter ;)

Comment: @kaiser haha - I oft get misspelled to my delight.

Comment: My bad, I probably wasn't clear enough! Check my edit in my question! :) Also tried not de-registering the widget (i.e. with just a `return;`, but still same results.

Comment: Don't worry! Figured it out! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for following up with an answer. Cheers.